# How to use slide menu (Same as facebook menu) and tabbar together

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

Please check below code . I need to implement tabbar and facebook slide menu together.

tabBarController.delegate = self;

```
self.leftController = [[LeftViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftViewController" bundle:nil];
RightViewController* rightController = [[RightViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RightViewController" bundle:nil];

// ViewController *centerController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
FirstViewController *centerController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
self.centerController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerController];
IIViewDeckController* deckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.centerController
                                                                                leftViewController:self.leftController
                                                                               rightViewController:rightController];
deckController.rightSize = 100;

self.window.rootViewController = deckController;

// Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

Comment: I found one open source control that works with 1,2,3 but doesn't work with uitabbarcontroller. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/saslidemenu

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're using the IIViewDeckController, look at its automaticallyUpdateTabBarItems property.